# Change JPanel after press JButton

Tags: jpanel, jbutton

i want to change JPanels by pressing the JButton. Well i can do that one time , but the problem is when i want to back to the previous JPanel . Here is my code:

```
public class MindCreations {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Adj0 object1= new Adj0();
    object1.setSize(500, 600);
    object1.setVisible(true);
    object1.setLocation(700,300);
} }

  public class Adj0 extends JFrame{
           public Adj0(){
     super("MindCreations");
     this.setLayout(null);

     adj0panel object9=new adj0panel();
     add(object9.adj0panel());
     Isa object10=new Isa();
     add(object10.Isa());
    } }

   public class adj0panel {
           private JButton quarto;
           private FlowLayout layout;

        public JPanel adj0panel(){

        final JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JLabel jl=new JLabel();
        panel.setLayout(layout);
            quarto= new JButton("Tabela ISA");
            quarto.setBounds(50,490,400,20);
            jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("2.png"));
        jl.setBounds(40, 50, 413, 300);

            panel.add(jl);
            panel.add(quarto);

            quarto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Isa object3=new Isa();
        panel.setVisible(false);
    }
      });
return panel;
   }
 }

  public class Isa {
     public JPanel Isa(){

            final JPanel panel1=new JPanel();

    panel1.setLayout(layout);
    panel1.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 600);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel1.setVisible(true);

          JButton retroceder=new JButton("Retroceder");
    retroceder.setBounds(300, 460, 90, 20);

    retroceder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            adj0panel object4=new adj0panel();
            panel1.setVisible(false);

            }}
    );

          panel1.add(retroceder);
    return panel1;
}}
```

I want to press the Button "retroceder" , and i want to go to JPanel from adj0panel class. Sorry for the long question , i'm a begginer in this .
If is there any other way to change JPanels please tell me .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

So to start, as you have probably figured out, a JFrame can only contain one JPanel in its container.

This:

```
frame.getContentPane();
```

is considered the "top-level" JPanel. You can add and remove panels to the top-level, much in the same way you're doing now. To keep track of multiple panels, I would get a Stack and a push() pop() method wired to your button that would at first push all panels onto the master JPanel, and then pop off from the stack and remove the corresponding JPanel from the proverbial stack in the master container.

setVisible() can work, but if you have multiple Panels, the top-most panel can "hide" the panels underneath itself, leading to unexpected results from setVisible(). Swing is tough.
Here's the docs that back this up:
[Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: hmm i see , but where in my program i can add "frame.getContentPane()" , should i add in the actionlistener of the JButton"retroceder", and if yes , how should i write him?

Comment: I would write a loader method that takes the frame as a param, and another method takes the frame's panel and loads the panels from the stack object. I assume this stuff could be in your main method or a PanelLoader factory-style class

Answer (score 0):

i tried to make a loader , idk if it was this that you told me , but maybe it works anyway.

```
    public class Adj0 extends JFrame{

     private FlowLayout layout; 

      public Adj0(){
    super("MindCreations");
    this.setLayout(layout);
    this.setSize(500, 600);
    this.setLocation(700,300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    dsa(1);

    }

public void dsa(int test){
    Isa object10 =new Isa();    
    adj0panel object0 =new adj0panel();

    if(test==1){
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();
    this.setContentPane(object0.adj0panel());
    this.getContentPane().revalidate();
    repaint();
    this.setLayout(null);

}
    else if(test==2){
        this.getContentPane().removeAll();
        this.setContentPane(object10.Isa());
        this.getContentPane().revalidate();
        this.setVisible(true);
        repaint();
        this.setLayout(null);

    }
    }
```

and then in the button i wrote this :

```
       quarto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        Adj0 object3=new Adj0();
        object3.dsa(2);
```

the thing is , when i press the button this create a new Jframe with the panel that i want, i only want to change the content. I think i'm not removing the previous contentpane the right way... maybe you can tell me some tips .